# Is there a way I can hide a button when checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: c++, winapi

I working to make a program that the user must agree to continue with the program.

The user must check the checkbox to continue, if the user check the checkbox, the "RUN" button displayed, and if he unchecked the checkbox, the button is hidden.

I have two problems with my program, when the user unchecked the checkbox, the "RUN" button does not disappeared, and the second problem is that when the user click on the "RUN" button, my program thinks that the user clicked on the checkbox and check or unchecked the checkbox.

This is my whole program, I would be very happy if you helped me.
If you want you can debug this program and see my problems.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam);
const char *title = "Check Box";

HWND agree, button;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE currentInstance, HINSTANCE previousInstance, PSTR cmdLine, INT cmdCount)
{
    // Register the window class
    const char* CLASS_NAME = "myWin32WindowClass";
    WNDCLASS wc{};
    wc.hInstance = currentInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 20, 20));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcessMessages;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND main = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, "WastedBit  1.6.2",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,   // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,               // Window initial position
        950, 750,                       // Window size
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    // TopMost
    SetWindowPos(main, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    // Window loop
    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        button = CreateWindow("button", 0,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
            20, 490, 15, 15,
            hwnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
        }
        else if (CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED) == TRUE) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            agree = CreateWindow("button", "RUN", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 750, 525, 150, 150, hwnd, (HMENU)button, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED) == TRUE) {
            ShowWindow(agree, SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create both objects (the check box AND the button) in WM_CREATE, you will get the `handleButton` back.
And the hiding should happens in WM_COMMAND then like this:

```
BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
 if (checked)
    ShowWindow(handleButton, SW_HIDE);
 else
    ShowWindow(handleButton, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Thanks! but it does not working, the button creates when the program start, and I can't even check the checkbox.

Comment: No matter, its now working. But when I click on the "RUN" button, the button unchecked and the "RUN" button disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

My program works great with @duDE's help.

I put the button and the checkbox in WM_CREATE, I make the button to be invisible when created, but when the user check the checkbox, the button is created.

- I wouldn't consider it a problem, but once the "RUN" button is pressed, the button disappears and the checkbox return to be unchecked.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        button = CreateWindow("button", 0,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
            20, 490, 15, 15,
            hwnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->hInstance, NULL);
        agree = CreateWindow("button", "RUN", WS_CHILD, 750, 525, 150, 150, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
            ShowWindow(agree, SW_HIDE);
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            ShowWindow(agree, SW_SHOW);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
```